# How can i obtaining GoogleCredentials using OAuth 2.0 Client ID in Java?

Tags: google-oauth, google-photos-api, google-client-login

I'm not good at English,
so My sentence is probally weird, I'm sorry

I'm making web project in first time,
then i just want to use google photo api

so i read [Get started with Java client library](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started-java#get-library)

```
// Set up the Photos Library Client that interacts with the API
PhotosLibrarySettings settings =
     PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
    .setCredentialsProvider(
        FixedCredentialsProvider.create(/* Add credentials here. */)) 
    .build();

try (PhotosLibraryClient photosLibraryClient =
    PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)) {

    // Create a new Album  with at title
    Album createdAlbum = photosLibraryClient.createAlbum("My Album");

    // Get some properties from the album, such as its ID and product URL
    String id = album.getId();
    String url = album.getProductUrl();

} catch (ApiException e) {
    // Error during album creation
}
```

I have OAuth client Id, secret with Json file
but i can't understand how can i get credentials

I spend this in 5 days...
how can i get credentials using OAuth 2.0 Client ID in Java?
Or can you teach me Associated Keywords?

I read api documnet,github
and Associated blogs
and ask for chatgpt over and over
but i can't find a way at all

[github about google-auth-library-java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java#google-auth-library-oauth2-http)
[github about java-photoslibrary](https://github.com/google/java-photoslibrary)
[google photo api document](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started-java#get-library)

Comment: credentials is the json file you download from google cloud console.   I am not sure I have seen any java examples with web credentials.